# Vue receiving data from the server

Tags: vue.js, async-await, store, vuex

Just want to say that I am became familiar with vue not so long ago.
Now I am having a problem.

I fetch data from the server.

// store
   import PostService from '../services/PostService'

```
export default {
  state: {
    posts: [],

  },
  actions: {
    async getPost() {
      const response = await PostService.fetchPosts();
      console.log(response.data.posts);

      this.posts = response.data.posts

    }
  }
}
```

There is an array for data and a request to the server.
In `response`, the data comes.

```
// vue component 
<template>
    <section class="posts--wrap">
        <div class="posts wrapper">
            <h1>Posts</h1>
            <div
                    class="posts__item--wrap"
                    v-if="this.allPosts.length"
            >
                <h3>List of posts</h3>
                <div
                        v-for="(post, index) in allPosts"
                        :key="index"
                        class="posts__item">
                    <h3 class="posts__item-title">{{post.title}}</h3>
                    <p class="posts__item-text">{{post.description}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div
                    v-else
                    class="posts__item-error"
            >
                <h3>There are no posts ... Lets add one now!</h3>
                <router-link tag="div" :to="{name: 'Add'}">
                    <a>Add new post ;)</a>
                </router-link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapState } from 'vuex';
    import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

    export default {
      name: 'PostPage',
      data () {
        return {

        }
      },
      computed: mapState({
        allPosts: state => state.posts.posts
      }),
      methods: {
        ...mapActions({
          getAllPosts: 'getPost'
        })
      },
      mounted() {
        console.log(this.allPosts);
        this.getAllPosts();
      }
    }
</script>
```

If add something to `state.posts`, it will be displayed on the page.

But I can't figure out how to get the data from the `response` into the `posts`
I ask for help, or hints.
Thank!

UPD
Made changes for which displays the `response`

response.log

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {_id: "5be4bbfaad18f91fbf732d17", title: "Title post 1", description: "esxdfgdfghj"}
1: {_id: "5be490f930fba81a704867f6", title: "2312", description: "312312312"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: can we see what the console.log of the response shows please.

Comment: @Andrew1325 I updated the question

Comment: Your response object doesn't have a property named data. Take a look at API, I mean you have to know the structure of the response object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did wrong in your action `getPost`, the proper way to change a state through an action is to commit a `mutation` using action `context` parameter like this:

```
...
mutations: {
    setPosts(state, posts) {
        state.posts = posts;
    },
},
actions: {
    async getPost(context) {
        /* ... */
        context.commit('setPosts', response.data.posts);
    }
},
...
```

[Read more about Vuex actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#actions).